# Does the Ferengi Alliance contain planets that have been conquered?

Tags: star-trek, ferengi

Their first appearance in *TNG* were supposed to be menacing and, along with the Cardassians (who came later), they were one of the new powers who were to be a threat, alongside the Borg.

Everything we know about their backstory mostly comes from the later *DS9* show, and while Quark certainly made many self-righteous monologues about how Ferengi are traders, not conquerors, this comes off as something of a retcon.

**Do we know if the Ferengi Alliance contains planets that were **conquered** by the Ferengi in earlier times?**

Comment: There wasn't originally much information to go on other than that they didn't share the morals and values of the Federation. That's why they got so easily discarded in favor of the Cardassians and Borg, which allowed them to be more fleshed out in DS9. There wasn't as much of a retcon because there wasn't anything to retcon yet.

Comment: I imagine that any conquering they did do was via more financial, rather than military, means. (Make contact, "invest" in the local economy, then assume control.)

Comment: Quark claims the Ferengi have never been involved in an interstellar war. 
 https://youtu.be/W5J_qn93Nkc

Comment: It may also be notable that if taken literally the female travel ban would make setting up colonies difficult.  I don't believe in single planet warp civilizations - but it is a comment on the source material canon.

Answer (score 4):

The Ferengi aren't necessarily benign, they just hold profit in such high regard that conquest doesn't seem to be a common societal goal. The Ferengi-controlled areas are called the [Ferengi Alliance](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ferengi_Alliance). A [fan made map](https://brilliantmaps.com/star-trek-map/) depicts their space as thus

[image: Ferengi Space]

Some of that map comes from recent canon (there was an out-of-focus map in *Star Trek: Picard*), so it may reflect post-DS9 events. [Dopteria](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dopteria), for instance (which is presumably the home of [Dopterians](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dopterian), described as "cousins of the Ferengi"), would seem unlikely to be conquered, as opposed to aligned. We don't know much about this alliance, only that it preferred to stay neutral.

You can also see they don't have much area to expand to before running up against much more powerful adversaries. They're squarely between the Federation (right), Breen (above) and Cardassians (below). While it is possible they have conquered planets, that list would be incredibly short.

Comment: You can conquer through economics and that is probably how it happened.